# String every 3 words new line

Tags: java, string

I have a programm and as title says  i want to split a string 
i take the stings from a database i dont know exactly what contains every string 
 for example

```
String locat = "london BLANCHE CAFE ET COCKTAIL BAR"
```

i want the output to be

first line "london BLANCHE CAFE" and secont line  "ET COCKTAIL BAR"

Comment: I would suggest using Split(), StringBuilder() as one simple approach.

Comment: maybe i didnt explain well what i need ... the string was an example i have many strings i take them from Database i dont know what icludes every string i want a pattern to give new line every 3 words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple solution using regex:

```
    String newLocat = locat.replaceAll("((?:\\w+\\s){2}\\w+)(\\s)", "$1\n");
```

Answer (score 3):

Many ways to do that. Just a random simple logic

```
String locat = "london BLANCHE CAFE ET COCKTAIL BAR";
int count =0;
StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(locat);

while (s.hasMoreTokens()) {
         count++;
         System.out.print(s.nextToken() + " ");
         if(count%3==0)System.out.println();
     }
```

Comment: You lose the spaces between the words.

Comment: No problem..As far as the requirement is met..:)

Comment: It is not. Your code gives `londonBLANCHECAFE` and `ETCOCKTAILBAR`, but `london BLANCHE CAFE` and `ET COCKTAIL BAR` is expected.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
final String locat = "london BLANCHE CAFE ET COCKTAIL BAR";
final String[] words = locat.split(" ");
final StringBuilder newLocat = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if ((i > 0) && (0 == (i % 3))) {
        newLocat.append('\n');
    }

    newLocat.append(words[i]);

    if (i != (words.length - 1)) {
        newLocat.append(' ');
    }
}

System.out.println(newLocat);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a line break to the string `"\n"`

`String locat = "london BLANCHE CAFE \nET COCKTAIL BAR"`